# Retrieving corresponding column values based on row label

Tags: r

So i have a set of data in excel:

```
StudID          Score            Participation

100              54                  0.43
432              70                  0.65
321              98                  0.96
100              65                  0.55
```

and I read it into R:

```
stud_stat <- read.csv("student.csv")
```

What I'm trying to do now is to only retrieve the score and participation values based on a specific ID. For example, if the ID is 100 i would want:

```
StudID          Score            Participation

 100             54                  0.43
 100             65                  0.55
```

I did something like:

```
find <- stud_stat[which(stud_stat$StudID == "100")]
```

and I'm getting an error mentioning about **undefined columns selected**.

Comment: `find <- stud_stat[which(stud_stat$StudID == "100"),]` you forgot the ",".

Comment: Or you could just do `subset(stud_stat, StudID == "100")`